# Make some OnIdiom and OnPlatform StaticResource

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to use `StaticResource` and benefits from auto complete of VS 2017 by using some syntax like this if it is exist:

```
<x:Double x:Key="NormalSpacing">
    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
        <OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="7" Android="3" />
        </OnIdiom.Phone>
        <OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="15" Android="10" />
        </OnIdiom.Tablet>
    </OnIdiom>
</x:Double>
```

shortly I want to give the key to the main tag which contain `OnIdiom` and `OnPlatform` tags.

Answer (score 2):

Use a style for auto complete with the compact `OnIdiom` and `OnPlatform`syntax:

```
<Style x:Key="stackLayoutStyle" TargetType="StackLayout">
    <Setter Property="Spacing" 
            Value="{OnIdiom 
        Phone  = {OnPlatform iOS=7,  Android=3   },
        Tablet = {OnPlatform iOS=15, Android=10 }}" >
    </Setter>
</Style>
...
<StackLayout Style="{StaticResource stackLayoutStyle}">
...
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I use style for another things, is there any other way?